# Finding date and battle of wounding for First World War English Private Arthur Higgins in France?

Tags: england, military-records, world-war-1, france

My father, Private Arthur Higgins No 2163, was born 4 Jul 1893, and was in the 5th Battalion of the North Staffordshire Regiment which landed in France on 5 Mar 1915 and was repatriated to England on 19 Oct 1915.

I wish to find out the date he was wounded and the Battle Front at which that occurred?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH.SE!  You don't say where you've tried to search already, so I wanted to alert you to the free access period this weekend on Ancestry.co.uk.  Their promo says "Access to the records in the featured collections will be free from 5 June at 00:01 until 7 June, 2015 at 23:59 GMT."  (Note that while there is a big button encouraging you to sign up for a 14-day free trial that is NOT necessary to view records during the free period.) While you are waiting for answers, take a look around at other questions here tagged world-war-1 and see if there is information that can help you.

Comment: Great steer from @Jan Murphy as the best place to find out will be if his WW1 service record survived. Regimental diaries may well help locate theatre of action. In the meantime, I would suggest a likely location was Ploegsteert Wood, near Ypres, where 1st Bn North Staffs lost men who died on 13 and 14 Oct 1914.

Comment: http://www.greatwar.co.uk/ estimates that only 40% of the service records survived and some of them are in very poor condition.

Comment: http://www.1914-1918.net/nstaffs.htm/  This site indicates that the 1st Btn was in France from 12 Sep 1914. The 5th Btn was reservists.

Comment: Whereas the 1/5th btn arrived in France on 4 Mar 1915. I think you might have got the year wrong.

Comment: @user3310902 I think you should write a short answer to summarise your comments